# Should I receive all messages after QLocalSocket is disconnected?

Tags: c++, qt, unix-socket, qlocalsocket

I have an application in c++/Qt in Windows, Linux and MacOSX, and I have a local client-server mechanism using Qt Local Server/Socket.

When the server refuses a connection, I send a message and close the socket, using [QLocalSocket::disconnectFromServer()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalsocket.html#disconnectFromServer)

From the documentation I see

> If there is pending data waiting to be written, QLocalSocket will enter ClosingState and wait until all data has been written.

So in the client side, I connect the signal [QLocalSocket::disconnected](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalsocket.html#disconnected) and do the following in my slot

```
void MyClientClass::onSocketDisconnected()
{
   qDebug() << "Socket disconnected";
   socket->readAll();
    //I do something with the data read
}
```

But it happens that sometimes, mostly on slow Linux machines (I try with virtual machines with only 1 processor), I do not receive the last message that the server send just before closing.

Why this happens? It should be in contrast with the documentation, shouldn't it?

Is there some motivation why I noticed it only in Linux and MacOSX (where Qt uses unix domain sockets) and I did not noticed it in Windows (where Qt uses pipes)?

Maybe there is some motivation related to domain sockets? Or I just misunderstood something?

Edit: as written in the comments below, in these cases when I do not receive the message, also the `QLocalSocket::ClosingState` is missing and I receive directly the `QLocalSocket::UnconnectedState`

Edit 2: as suggested in comments, I tried the `waitForReadyRead()` function. I did it `onSocketDisconnected()` and also `onStateChanged()` when the state goes to `QLocalSocket::ClosingState` or `QLocalSocket::UnconnectedState`. When I receive the `QLocalSocket::ClosingState` everything goes well, but the problem, as I said in the last edit, is that sometimes `QLocalSocket::ClosingState` is missing. In this case, the `waitForReadyRead()` fails without waiting the timeout and I have a warning "QIODevice:read (QTcpSocket): device not open" (even if I am using `QLocalSocket`, maybe the warning message is not updated well in Qt source). By the way, I am using Qt5.7.

Comment: Maybe you have to handle `QLocalSocket::stateChanged()` signal and its `QLocalSocket::ClosingState` state in the corresponding slot? I guess the `disconnected()` signal emits after `stateChanged()` one.

Comment: hi vahancho, thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it does not work...I logged the `stateChanged()` signal and I get only the `QLocalSocket::UnconnectedState` after a `QLocalSocket::PeerClosedError`. The `QLocalSocket::ClosingState` sometimes is missing. I try to read the available data in two slots, `onError()` and `onStateChange()`, but I still don't get the last message (in Ubuntu16 virtual machine with 1 processor and 1gb RAM I can reproduce it 30% of times).

Comment: You are reading the socket _without waiting it to complete writing_ so you have to connect to the signal `waitForReadyRead()` in order to read a socket correctly.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I will try your suggestion. Anyway, it is written in doc in `disconnectFromServer()` function that "will enter ClosingState and _wait until all data has been written_". A part of that, I also do a redundary `flush()` _before_ closing it. But I will try and tell you the result thanks. Edit: another thing. From `waitForReadyRead()` doc: "This function blocks until data is available for reading and the readyRead() signal has been emitted". I already check the `readyRead()` signal, so why should I wait?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I confirm that your suggestion did _not_ work :( see the edit question for the details.